# Difference between system_current and current for the vairable LOCAL_SDK_VERSION in ANDROID.mk?

Tags: android, android-source, android-sdk-manager, android-11, android.mk

Our application should be built along with Android build and moved to the system partition.

But we were using hidden api and so we added the variable `LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true`

In the current Android 11, we removed all the hidden api from our app and are trying to move our app to the /product partition .In the Android.mk file ,we added these changes

```
LOCAL_PRODUCT_MODULE := true
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
```

My question is about two possible values of the variable

1. `system_current`
2. `current`

Can anyone explain to me what the difference between `system_current` and `current` is?

Answer (score 1):

The `system_current` flag enables the system SDK APIs/symbols while the `current` uses the current prebuilt public SDK as per the android version of the source tree.

Soong (Android.bp) Releated Reference:
http://119.29.209.28/Android/soong/java.html#android_app.sdk_version

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/java-library